# HikariCP and Spring JPA

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, hikaricp

I was reading the documentation of Spring Boot and HikariCP and would like to integrate it to my SB app, but I got a little confused when it comes to Hikari and JPA.
I'm currently using Spring Data (`spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`) and my questions are: can I use HikariCP when using JPA? will it interfere on the way Hibernate connects to database? should I do some other configuration to make Hibernate using HikariCP? it wasn't really clear on documentations

Comment: HikariCP is a datasource / connection pool like any other. It is a datasource no more no less. For your JPA provider it doesn't matter as long as it is a `DataSource`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**There is no issue with using JPA and HikariCP together.** Depending on which JPA implementation you want to use you can look around a bit more, but generally Hibernate and EclipseLink are supported. For example here is an example using the exact set of technologies you described:

[HikariCP + JPA + spring-data](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-getting-the-required-dependencies/)

Comment: But do i need to configure HikariCP when using Spring boot ? Is there any meaning to do that ?